# Request get data yields none from a request sent from pc to django app

Tags: python, django, django-views, python-requests, httpresponse

I have a django app with views file set up as

```
def SomeView(response):
    if response.method == 'GET':
        data = response.GET.get("test")
    return HttpResponse(data)
```

and another python file i am using to make requests to my local django app like

```
import requests
payload = {'test': 1}
r = requests.get("127.0.0.1:8000" , data = payload)
print(r.text)
```

Basically i would like to return a http response based on the data sent through GET request so expected output is:

```
1
```

but the actual out i recieve is

```
None
```

Please guide me towards the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To encode data in the [*query string* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), you should use the [**`params=…`** parameter [requests-doc]](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls), not <s>`data=…`</s>:

```
import requests
payload = {'test': 1}
r = requests.get('127.0.0.1:8000', params=payload)
print(r.text)
```